# Can I switch away from full-screen DVD Player on a second monitor without having it exit full screen mode?

Tags: display, movie, projector, dvd-player

I am a part-time projectionist, and we use DVD Player to show the movies on the projector. Sometimes, though, I need to do something while the movie is playing. Unfortunately, if I try to switch applications, DVD Player exits full screen mode. Is there any way to retain full screen mode?

The computer in question is a Snow Leopard-running iMac connected via VGA to a generic projector.

Answer (score 1):

With my MacBook Pro, I can use multitouch gestures like swipe to the Desktop or to another screen using four fingers with my trackpad, and it does keep the movie in fullscreen, but this does depend on which DVD player you are using.

In my case, I use [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Comment: I'm using DVD Player.

Comment: Plus, I'm running Snow Leopard, as I said.